# C++ check how many same elements in a row are in a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

I have a big vector with 24.000 elements like :

```
(1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,5,5,5,...etc)
```

and I want to check how many same elements are in a row like:
4-6-3..etc
I use this code :

```
static int counter=1;
vector<int>numbers;

for(int n=0;n<numbers.size()-1;n++)
{
  if(numbers[n]==numbers[n+1])
  {
    counter++;
  }
  else if(numbers[n]!=numbers[n+1])
  {
   cout<<counter<<endl;
   counter=1;
  }
}
```

is there any algorithm that does the same faster;

Comment: Is the vector sorted?

Comment: You can remove the second if() statement and should care about last element

Comment: @SonicpathSonicwave is a vector containing {1, 2, 3, 1} a possible input?

Comment: @stefan      yes it is

Comment: yes I know I have always to check manually for the last element  don't know how to do that in the code

Comment: @SonicpathSonicwave as you said the numbers were not sorted your algo is wrong , as it works only for sorted numbers...!! Ex:{ 1,1,3,3,1,1 } gives 2,2,2 but no of ones in your case are 4 and 3's are 2..!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@rhalbersma basically gave you the right answer. As an addendum, in case you want to rewrite your algorithm in a more standard fashion:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5 }; // or whatever...

    auto i = begin(v);
    while (i != end(v))
    {
        auto j = adjacent_find(i, end(v), std::not_equal_to<int>());
        if (j == end(v)) { std::cout << distance(i, j); break; }
        std::cout << distance(i, j) + 1 << std::endl;
        i = next(j);
    }
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://ideone.com/H1jdSs).

Also, when the vector is sorted, this will give you better best-case complexity:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5 }; // must be sorted...

    auto i = begin(v);
    while (i != end(v))
    {
        auto ub = upper_bound(i, end(v), *i);
        std::cout << distance(i, ub) << std::endl;
        i = ub;
    }
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://ideone.com/haCwYm).

Comment: +1 for the Standard Library usage. You are missing a `using namespace std;` in our example or some `std::` qualifiers here and there.

Comment: @rhalbersma: Unless I made some mistakes, those `std::` are unnecessary because of ADL. But yes, they could be there ;)

Comment: ah your ADL addiction kicks in again! we all have our vices :-) (I use `#pragma once` and no other include guards)

Comment: @rhalbersma: Btw, sorry for mistyping your username

Comment: next time I shall insist on my user id

Comment: @Andy Prowl  I am still trying to understand the code.
I have to go back to my c++ books.
Thanks a lot

Comment: @SonicpathSonicwave: Take your time ;) The standard library has powerful algorithms, but yes, not too easy to understand at a first glance

Comment: If there aren't too many of the same elements, I don't think the `upper_bound` approach will be faster. I believe that approach would be worst case O(n log n) (but best case O(log n)), while the native approach is always O(n). Also, a slight improvement may be to start from `i` - something like `upper_bound(i, end(v), *i)`.

Comment: @Dukeling: Thank you for the improvement, indeed I overlooked that

Comment: @Dukeling: For what concerns worst-case complexity in the sorted case, it seems to me you are right (edited again). Whether this brings advantages over an O(n) algorithm depends on the input

Comment: @Dukeling Agreed that repeated `upper_bound` calls have overall `O(N log N)` worst-case complexity (e.g. an array of all unique values). The problem is that every call of `adjacent_find` is `O(K)`, with `K` the length of the current run, whereas the `upper_bound` calls are `O(log N)`, not dependent on the  current run length. But isn't there any trick that for already sorted inputs can get their frequency counts guaranteed faster than `O(N)`? E.g. some call that finds the current run length in `O(log K)` would do it. I would find that very surprising!

Comment: @rhalbersma You can't beat worst-case O(n). For an array of unique values one would need to look at every element. There's no way to get around that. It's easy enough to prove by supposing we skip one element, then either that element is unique or equal to either element next to it, each of which would change the output.

Comment: @Dukeling correct, let me rephrase. the repeated `adjacent_find` is `theta(N)`, linear for best and worst case. the repeated `upper_bound` is `O(N lg N)` worst-case, with perhaps better average performance. There could be something with `O(N)` worst-case, with better average case. I'm thinking of doing a recursive partitioning of the input (by comparing whether there is a value jump at a partition point) and then printing the segment lengths between the partition points. a single valued input immediately returns, and `N`unique input values should take `O(N)`.

Answer (score 6):

Your algorithm is `O(N)` in time, and that seems pretty optimal to me since you have to visit every unique element for comparison. You might still shave off a few cycles here and there e.g. by **eliminating the condition inside the `else()`** or by turning on some compiler settings, but algorithmically you are in good shape.

If the input were already **sorted**, you could do a **series of binary searches**. That would give you `O(N lg N)` worst-case complexity but the     average case might be considerably lower depending on the average length of equal element sequences.

BTW, as @AndyProwl shows in his answer: the Standard Library is **really awesome** to do even this kind of low-level algorithmic stuff. The `adjacent_find` and `upper_bound` algorithms have well-documented complexities and the iterator conventions will guard you for edge cases that are present in your own code. Once you learn this vocabulary, you can easily use them  in your own routines (and when Ranges come to C++, hopefully it'll also easier to compose them).

Answer (score 0):

There is some litle optimization that may give you a few ms:

```
int size = numbers.size()-1;
static int counter=1;
static int *num1 = &numbers[0];
static int *num2 = &numbers[1];
for(int n=0;n<size;n++)
{
  if(*num1==*num2) counter++;
  else
  {
   cout << counter << "\n";
   counter=1;
  }
  num1++;
  num2++;
}
cout<<counter<<endl; //Caution, this line is missing in your code!!
```

Basicaly:

- Avoid access to the vector by id: numbers[n] mean that the computer must multiply n*sizeof(int) and add this result to numbers. Is faster to use pointer and increment it, that mean just an add.

Comment: then also remove the `endl` in the inner loop as it will flush the buffer every time, not just when it's full.

Comment: You are right!! I have edited this line.
Also, maybe there is something more efficient than iosteam for that.